# LUKS full disk encryption - autostart

Tags: encryption, autostart, luks

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.10
Set up disk encryption with passphrase and installation on whole disk. Now every start or reboot is asking for

```
Please unlock disk sda5_crypt
```

Is it possible to run the server encrypted without entering the passphrase every time?
I am scared of somebody stealing the server with data.
But I need the server to work after reboot too.

Is there a solution for this? Is it necessary to enter the passphrase after reboot or can the system work without it?

Comment: This is EXACTLY what encryption is intended for - to prevent unauthorized access to the data by people with physical access to the machine. If that's not your goal, then perhaps encryption isn't the right answer for you.

Comment: Sure, but can server operate without asking passphrase at any restart? Is there a way to protect data on working server?

Comment: Encryption protects data *at rest*. A working server is not at rest - the data is decrypted anyway. Encryption is the wrong solution for that use case.

Comment: A whole-disk-encrypted server CANNOT operate without the decryption key (passphrase). It's that simple. The OS files are encrypted and cannot be used until decrypted.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the big companies such as DigitalOcean and other offers encrypted data storage. What does it mean?

Comment: BTW. Can I encrypt only part of disk (not full) and operate with encrypted part? Without entering passphrase while restart.

Comment: Yes, you can encrypt files and directories. That's a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user535733 commented you cannot have privacy or integrity without authentication. If you could boot the system without a pass phrase then anybody could. However there are other authentication methods like key cards, fingerprint readers or other biometry; all of them require the presence of an authorized operator though.

Comment: You can also unlock luks via network in initramfs. There are some hooks for dropbear...